How do I identify participants that are causing low internal consistency?
I have a low cronbach's alpha for one my study's measures (around .6). Half of the measure is reverse coded, and these reverse coded items are the ones that were flagged with having low correlation with the other items.
We already expected that there's some possible fraud in the dataset, and so I'm wondering if what is happening is that a subset of the sample are answering the measure disingenuously with a pattern that deviates from the expected response pattern (e.g., scoring all of the items high, instead of answering reverse and non-reverse coded items in opposite directions).
What can I do to identify which participants are responding in this inconsistent way, so we can take a closer look at their data for other possible signs of fraud? I thought I could calculate outfit statistics with mirt::personfit and isolate the participants with std outfit > 1 to identify which participants were not fitting the data well, which was 17% of the sample. But when I excluded those participants the cronbach's alpha didn't change (and actually decreased a little). What should I do?
